# XSLT: Rename attribute if not exists

Tags: xml, xslt, stylesheet

I have a lot of XML files that contain attributes with a misspelled value:

```
<Part id="1">
  <Attribute Name="Colo" Value="Red" />
</Part>
```

`Colo` should be `Color`. Now in some files this has been corrected manually and then both attributes exist:

```
<Attribute Name="Colo" Value="Red" />
<Attribute Name="Color" Value="Blue" />
```

I have a XSL transformation that renames the `Colo` attribute to `Color` but I have no idea how to avoid that when the corrected attribute already exists.

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Attribute/@Name[. = 'Colo']">
    <xsl:attribute name="Name">
        <xsl:value-of select="'Color'"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

How to not rename if there already is the correct attribute?

Comment: Shouldn't you *remove* the entire `Attribute` element with a `Colo` Name when the corrected version exists?

Comment: That would be best and is what I do next :)

Comment: Confusing that your "attributes" are actually elements, and that their "names" are actually the values of their "name" attributes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Attribute[@Name = 'Colo']">
    <xsl:if test="not(../Attribute[@Name = 'Color'])">
        <Attribute Name="Color" Value="{@Value}" />
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This will modify the `Attribute` element with the misspelled name if it does not have a sibling with the correct name; otherwise it will just remove it.